# Why I cannot display an image on my web page using VichUploaderBundle and Symfony 5?

Tags: php, image, symfony, twig, vichuploaderbundle

I've installed and configured the VichUploader bundle on my Symfony (V5.2) project and yet, I cannot display the image I've uploaded and stored in my "$imageName" field of my DB. So, Could you give me some solutions, explanations or even some tracks to help me, please?

I give you my code to make easier the understanding :

vich_uploader.yaml :

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
       announcement_image:
            uri_prefix: /images/announcements
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/announcements'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\SmartUniqueNamer

            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

AnnoucementController (Well, I upload my image with the new method and everything work fine. But, when I execute the method siwOne which give all the of one specific announcement, the image is not displayed) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Announcement;
use App\Form\AnnouncementType;
use App\Repository\AnnouncementRepository;
use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class AnnouncementController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/announcement/show/list", name="show_list_announcement")
     * @param AnnouncementRepository $ar
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showList(AnnouncementRepository $ar): Response
    {
        $announces = $ar->findAll();
        return $this->render("post/announcement/showList.html.twig", ["announces" => $announces]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/announcement/show/one/{id}", name="show_one_announcement", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
     * @param $id
     * @param AnnouncementRepository $ar
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showOne($id, AnnouncementRepository $ar): Response
    {
            $announcement = $ar->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
            return $this->render("post/announcement/showOne.html.twig", ['announcement' => $announcement]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/announcement/new", name="new_announcement")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UsersRepository $ur
     * @return Response
     */
    public function new(Request $request, UsersRepository $ur): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $announcement = new Announcement();
        $form = $this->createForm(AnnouncementType::class, $announcement);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $announcement->setUser($user);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($announcement);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute("home");
        }
        return $this->render("post/announcement/create.html.twig",
            ["AnnouncementForm" => $form->createView()]);
    }
}
```

When I execute the "dd()" method in the showOne function, it displays the array below with the imageFile field set to null (Is there the problem which I looking for to solve ?) :

```
AnnouncementController.php on line 37:
App\Entity\Announcement {#4499 ▼
  -id: 10
  -title: "Ma 1ère annonces"
  -content: """
    Le lorem ipsum (également appelé faux-texte, lipsum, ou bolo bolo1) est, en imprimerie, une suite de mots sans signification utilisée à titre provisoire pour ca ▶
    
    Généralement, on utilise un texte en faux latin (le texte ne veut rien dire, il a été modifié), le Lorem ipsum ou Lipsum. L'avantage du latin est que l'opérateu ▶
    """
  -imageFile: null
  -imageName: "330px-horseshoe-falls-2-mt-field-national-park-61165eca3ce95432200637.jpg"
  -user: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User {#579 ▶}
  -created_At: DateTime @1628856009 {#755 ▼
    date: 2021-08-13 12:00:09.0 UTC (+00:00)
  }
  -updated_At: DateTime @1628856010 {#4887 ▼
    date: 2021-08-13 12:00:10.0 UTC (+00:00)
  }
}
```

AnnouncementType.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Announcement;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class AnnouncementType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class,['required' => true, 'label' => 'Titre'])
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class,['required' => true, 'label' => 'Contenu'])
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Illustration']);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Announcement::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Announcement.php (this class extends from post and has no attribute because a post could be an announcement but also a recipe or an article. Hence, I have to make an announcement class separately to make sense and respect the DB schema I've made before starting coding) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AnnouncementRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AnnouncementRepository::class)
 */
class Announcement extends Post
{

}
```

Post.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PostRepository;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository", repositoryClass=PostRepository::class)
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="post_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"post"="Post", "announcement"="Announcement"})
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="announcement_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
     *
     * @var File|null
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_At;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updated_At;

    /**
     * Post constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created_At = new DateTime();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|null $imageFile
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

        if (null !== $imageFile) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updated_At = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImageName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $imageName
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setImageName(?string $imageName): Post
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;
        return $this;
    }



    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->created_At;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $Created_At): self
    {
        $this->created_At = $Created_At;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updated_At;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $updated_At
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updated_At): void
    {
        $this->updated_At = $updated_At;
    }

}
```

showOne.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container mt-5 ml-4">
        <h3>{{ announcement.title }}</h3>
        <p>Publié le {{ announcement.createdAt | date("d/m/Y") }}</p>
        <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(announcement, 'imageFile') }}" alt="{{ announcement.imageName }}" style="width:100%; height: auto;" >
        <p>{{ announcement.content }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
    Annonce - {{ announcement.title }}
{% endblock %}
```

As I said, any help would be much appreciated!

Regards.

YT

Comment: Try `uri_prefix: images/announcements` (without a slash at the beginning) in your vich_uploader.yaml because everything else seems OK.

Comment: @Flash, I try to set the uri/prefix without slashes but it doesn't work.

Comment: So what you get as a `src` for your image in the result, and what is expected? I just thing that problem is in resulting route.

Comment: Here is what I have as src when I run the web page : 
`<img src="public/images/announcements/330px-horseshoe-falls-2-mt-field-national-park-61165eca3ce95432200637.jpg" alt="330px-horseshoe-falls-2-mt-field-national-park-61165eca3ce95432200637.jpg" style="width:100%; height: auto;">`

Comment: Try `{{ asset(vich_uploader_asset(announcement, 'imageFile')) }}`

Comment: It fires me this error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "C:\wamp64\www\avanza/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist.").

Comment: `inject_on_load: false` will cause `dd()` to show the property as `null`,  and is resolved by `vich_uploader_asset`, otherwise `src=` would be blank . You shouldn't need to use `asset()` Does the file at `public/images/announcements/330px-horseshoe-falls-2-mt-field-national-park-61165eca3ce95432200637.jpg` actually exist?

Comment: I found it out. There was a mistake in the uri_prefix key. The good one was avanza/public/images/announcements/name_of_the_file. Ty everyone for your responses!

Comment: @YacineTAZDAIT your Apache/nginx web root (`DocumentRoot`) should be `avanza/public/` so having a `url_prefix`  that is the same, indicates a server misconfiguration, since the Symfony core files/vendor etc would be in the web root and allow for people to type in the paths in the browser to view the config files. eg: `/avanza/config/packages/doctrine.yaml` or `/avanza/.git/config`, etc